# Custom Select option dropdown with close button

Tags: jquery, dropdown, html-select, custom-selectors

> I am new in the JavaScript i tried it lots of time but unable to do it. Can someone please help me out with below(image) for custom select box. And "+ New Category" steady bottom as shown in the image. Also want to use it multiple times on different places.

[image]

```
<select type="text" id="select-dropdown"  placeholder="Select Category" autocomplete="off">                                    
                                    <option>adda</option>
                                    <option>Alliance Engineering</option>
                                    <option>Asia Art Archive</option>
                                    <option>Astrit</option>
                                    <option>BharatFC</option>
                                    <option>Garware</option>
                                    <option>Krypt Inc.</option>
                                    <option>+ New Category</option>                            
                                </select>
```